# Adding a receipt page on woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I am developing a payment gateway for woocommerce.
I read many tutorial of how I can manage to do it but I can't figure out what this line of code mean:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_receipt_paypal', array( $this, 'receipt_page' ) );
```

Especially, there is no function called woocommerce_receipt_paypal and how can I reproduce it in my plugin.

Answer (score 5):

You have to replace

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_receipt_paypal', array( $this, 'receipt_page' ) );
```

with

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_receipt_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'receipt_page' ) );
```

where `id` is the one you set in `__construct()` function.

Comment: I have added this line and still doesn't work. Can you explain how did you figure it out?

Comment: even after many years, this answer rocked, thanks